# Is is possible to reposition or destroy a sprinkler?

Tags: stardew-valley

I missclicked when placing my sprinkler and screwed up my layout. Is there a way to reposition/destroy it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can re-position almost all place-able objects in the game besides Seeds and objects that degrade like fences. There are several methods:

- You can use your pickaxe, hoe or axe on most objects to pop them out of the ground.
- Objects in your house like you TV you can simply left click and drag around at will. You can also rotate these by right-clicking.
- Most objects you can also pull out by standing directly next to them, facing in the direction of the object, with a completely empty equipment slot and holding left-click. They will shake and eventually pop out.
- Most wood based objects, like fences, require that you use your axe and the hoe and pickaxe will not work.

Note: Objects that degrade (again, like fences) have a time limit for when you can successfully take them back though. It is more than a day at the least so you are free to place and pick up fences as many time as you wish, just make sure it's where you want it before you go to bed for the night.

Sprinklers, and most other crafted items, do not degrade and therefore can be placed and picked up and re-placed as many times as you wish over any period of time.

Comment: As far as I can recall, it actually doesn't matter which tool (pickaxe vs. axe) that you use, both will dislodge placed objects.

Comment: You don't even need a tool equipped, just hold right-click.  The tool will shake a few times, then it will pop out.

Comment: What?! I guess some stuff reacts to both clicks so I just switch between them and must have never noticed the difference.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You are incorrect. I just checked. I just right-clicked and held right-click with my watering can equipped and nothing happened.

Comment: I said no tool equipped...

Comment: You also said right click... I will update my answer. I figured it out. You have to be directly facing an object and have nothing in your current slot and hold left-click.

Comment: You can avoid the opposite problem (_accidentally_ hitting a sprinkler with your hoe and dislodging it) by putting down a square of flooring and then putting the sprinkler on top of it.  Then you can still use an upgraded hoe to plow a lot of squares without knocking loose your sprinklers.  You can still use a pickaxe to dislodge the sprinker.

Comment: @Reafexus Your first sentence contradicts the fourth bullet point.

Comment: I recently discovered that you can use the third bullet to move non-empty chests. You can't pick up a non-empty chest with the pickaxe (or else you'd get a "nesting doll" inventory with extra space), but you can nudge a filled chest one square at a time by clicking repeatedly or holding down a click with empty hands.